# How to rebuild a record from a change log

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of changes to an entity. I am trying to rebuild the data from the changes.

This is my `Changes` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Changes 
(
    Id IDENTITY, 
    RecordId INT, 
    Field INT, 
    Val VARCHAR(MAX), 
    DateOfChange DATETIME
);
```

`Field` column is a reference to what field changed, `Val` is the new value, `RecordId` is the Id of the record that changed. Ideally the `Record` table would contain the latest values but I am not that lucky. There are 10 different fields that changes are tracked, mostly dates but some other types are thrown in there.

This is my `Record` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Records 
(
    Id IDENTITY, 
    AUserGeneratedIdentifer VARCHAR(12)
)
```

I'd like to have a view to query by the rolled up values.

```sql
SELECT 
    AUserGeneratedIdentitfier, DateOpened, DateClosed, etc 
FROM 
    RecordView
WHERE 
    AUserGeneratedIdentitfier = 'something'
```

I am trying to implemented it with CTEs but I am wondering if this is the correct way. I am using a CTE per field I am trying to get to.

```sql
WITH DateOpened AS 
(
    SELECT 
        RecordId, Val, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RecordId ORDER BY DateOfChanged DESC) Rank
    FROM 
        Changes
    WHERE 
        FieldId = @DateOpenedId
) --- ... Repeat for every field
SELECT (my fields)
FROM Records
INNER JOIN <all ctes> on Record Id
```

But this method feels wrong to me, possibly due to my lack of SQL experience. Is there a better way that I am missing here? What are the performance implications of having multiple CTEs on the same table and joining with them?

Please excuse the hastily thrown together pseudo code, I hope it illustrates my problem accurately

Comment: Your question would be clearer with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to use a single ROW_NUMBER and pivot it as below.

```
DECLARE @Records TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY, AUserGeneratedIdentifer VARCHAR(12))
DECLARE @Changes TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY, RecordId INT, Field INT, Val VARCHAR(MAX), DateOfChange DATETIME);

INSERT INTO @Records (AUserGeneratedIdentifer)
VALUES ('qwer'), ('asdf')


INSERT INTO @Changes (RecordId, Field, Val, DateOfChange)
VALUES  (1, 1, 'foo', '2021-01-01' ),
        (2, 1, 'fooz', '2021-01-01' ),
        (2, 2, 'barz', '2021-01-01' ),
        (1, 2, 'bar', '2021-01-01' ),
        (1, 1, 'foo2', '2021-01-02' ),
        (2, 2, 'barz2', '2021-01-02' )

SELECT piv.RecordId, piv.[1], piv.[2] 
FROM (
  SELECT C.RecordId, C.Field, C.Val, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.RecordId, C.Field ORDER BY C.DateOfChange DESC) RowNum
  FROM @Changes C
  ) sub
PIVOT (
  MAX(Val)
  FOR Field IN ([1], [2])
) piv
WHERE piv.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: That is much cleaner! I like it. So if I need to join that with another table should I do it in the sub query or in the outer query?

Comment: Tbh I'd probably alias this whole thing as a cte and join to that. Or alias it as a subquery if you're more used to that. Pivots introduce an implicit grouping so you have to be careful about adding extra fields to the pivoted query itself.